# C# Drag and Drop sem um evento especifico

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `C#(WPF)` e gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como obter os dados do `drag n drop` do mouse sem nenhum evento ser disparado.

Existe alguma maneira de retornar esses dados do `dragndrop` do mouse(um arquivo sendo arrastado por exemplo) sem nenhum evento específico ou se é possível simular o `Drop` e obter os dados do Mouse naquele momento?

Comment: Acho que não entendi a pergunta. Os eventos serão disparados de qualquer forma, seja o evento do Drag, Drop, Click, etc...

Comment: Oi Vinicius, eu quero obter um arquivo sendo arrastado pelo Mouse sem utilizar nenhum controle-evento do meu aplicativo. Quero detectar o arquivo sem meu aplicativo estar aberto. Eu já sei o momento certo, só não sei como acessar os dados do Mouse fora da aplicação... No namespace Input.Mouse só consigo informações sobre a posição do mouse, já o conteudo do drag-n-drop não consigo acessar...